# How To Upload File with Django Rest APi

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

can someone help me how to upload file with POST method in django rest api, 
for example when I launch

```
curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/assets/ -d '{"name" = "my image   ","source"="/root/images/my_image2.jpg"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I want to upload my_image2.jpg

serializers.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Asset

class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
```

views.py:

```
from .serializers import AssetSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


class AssetAdd(APIView):


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AssetSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        print serializer.data

        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
class Asset(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=200)
    source = models.FileField(_('file'), upload_to=upload_to, storage=default_storage)

    ext = models.CharField(max_length=15, editable=False)
    type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ASSET_TYPE, max_length=15, editable=False)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=32, default=0, editable=False)

    _file_meta = models.TextField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)

    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)
```

I'm newbie in Django REST API , I read documentation  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers.html#fileuploadparser , but still don't undestand how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload)

Answer (score 25):

First of all you need to define a parser in your view. This is because the API needs to know which headers to look for. Browsers transfer files as form-data, so you need to use the MultiPartParser and FormParser together. You can also use the FileUploadParser but you need to make sure your client is sending the correct HTTP headers.

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser

class AssetAdd(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
```

Then, in the post method, your file will be present in the FILES QueryDict:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    my_file = request.FILES['file_field_name']
    filename = '/tmp/myfile'
    with open(filename, 'wb+') as temp_file:
        for chunk in my_file.chunks():
            temp_file.write(chunk)

    my_saved_file = open(filename) #there you go
```

Comment: please can you explain me in more details,

Comment: I added class AssetAdd(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        my_file = request.FILES['file_field_name']
        print my_file

Comment: when I tried to execute {"name": "San Francisco Bridge", "source": "assets/34/3492/3492AA/3492AA/source.jpg"} , but get error {
    "detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None"
}

Comment: I tried curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/assets/ -d '{"name": "San Francisco Bridge", "source": "assets/34/3492/3492AA/3492AA/source.jpg"}' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
 but get error   { "detail": "Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None" }   ???

Comment: Yeah... uhm, file uploads and curl don't work that way, you can't send the file route in your computer and expect the system to know it has to retrieve the file. Also, what you're sending is not multi-part because it doesn't have a file attached. Take a look at this: https://ariejan.net/2010/06/07/uploading-files-with-curl/

Comment: Where can I import the MultiPartParser and FormParser from?

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom `from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser`

Comment: @fixmycode Can you help me with question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833413/django-rest-upload-file-and-invalid-email

Answer (score 0):

Write your models like this:

```
from django.db import models
class PicModel(models.Model):
    file_to_be_uploaded = models.FileField(upload_to='/directory/where/you/what/to/upload/to')
```

if you uploading images then ImageField but install pillow by `pip install pillow`.

In you `serializers.py` assuming you are using `rest_framework`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app_name.models import PicModel

class PicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PicModel
        fields = '__all__' #or any way you may like to display you fields
```

In you `views.py` include assuming you are to using class-base views:

```
from app_name.models import PicModel
from app_name.serializers import PicModelSerializer
#other necessary imports

class PicList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):#or format can be json or api
        serializer = PicModelSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            ............more code
```

To test in json data write like:

```
{
    "file_to_be_uploaded":"//path//to//file//on//local//machine"
}
```