# Django rest framework - File Upload with Ajax , Multipartparser

Tags: ajax, django, rest, multipartform-data

I'm new bee of django rest framework & django.

I can handle some code for CRUD feature using JSON/Ajax in django rest_framework.
Now, I want to use feature file uploading especially Image file.

But, I searched some pieces of code, and try some code (like https://github.com/ansother/multipart-form-data_django_rest_framework_tutorial  , it is really helpful, but I cannot fully understood, and not worked.)

So, I want to know about file uploading using rest frmaework & some parser(views), serializer

This is my models.py

```
class ImageFile(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='/Users/riskkim/soma/')
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to reference to write file upload example using rest_framework, ajax

Comment: Please refer my answer to a similar question: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38388300/454023)