# Django Rest Framework upload file to a method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So i have been trying to upload a file to a method using DRF with no luck so far.

I was able to upload to a `ModelViewSet` using `(FormParser, MultiPartParser,)` with no problems, but i really need to use it in something like this `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/women/{pk}/upload_avatar/` where i want to first filter the woman by id and upload to her avatar (which is a foreign key to a multimedia model). I tried using a nested resource library with no luck.

So far i have in my modelviewset:

```
class WomenNativePassportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Women.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WomenNativePassportSerializer
    authentication_classes = (NoAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)

    @detail_route(
        methods=['post', 'put', 'patch', 'get'], permission_classes=[AllowAny],
        authentication_classes=[NoAuthentication], serializer_class=MultimediaSerializer,
        parser_classes=(FormParser, MultiPartParser,)
    )
    def upload_avatar(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'POST' in request._method or 'PATCH' in request._method:
            # Write code to save the file??
        else:
            multimedia = Multimedia.objects.filter(user_profiles_avatares__pk=pk)
            page = self.paginate_queryset(multimedia)
            serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My models:

```
class Women(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(
        'core.Multimedia', blank=True, null=True,
        related_name='user_profiles_avatares'
    )

class Multimedia(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
```

Basically i want to know if this is the right path i am taking, and if yes how can i properly save the uploaded file in the model??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some code of what i did to overcome this problem. Although Kevin Brown answer probably works, i find my code a little "easier" approach:

```
    @detail_route(
        methods=['post', 'put', 'patch', 'get'], permission_classes=[AllowAny],
        authentication_classes=[NoAuthentication], serializer_class=MultimediaSerializer,
        parser_classes=(FormParser, MultiPartParser,)
    )
    def upload_avatar(self, request, pk=None):
        # Because we are using nested resources this was the only way i found to
        # upload a file. Maybe there is a better way
        if request.method in ['PATCH', 'POST']:
            avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar')
            if not avatar:
                return Response(status=404)

            try:
                woman = WomenNativePassport.objects.get(pk=pk)
            except WomenNativePassport.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status=404)
            else:
                request.FILES['thumbnail'] = request.FILES['avatar']
                serializer = AvatarSerializer(
                    data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES
                )
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    woman.avatar.thumbnail.save(str(avatar), File(avatar))
                    return Response(status=204)
                else:
                    return Response(status=404)
        else:
            multimedia = Multimedia.objects.filter(user_profiles_avatares__pk=pk)
            page = self.paginate_queryset(multimedia)
            serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
            return Response(serializer.data)


# serializer 

class AvatarSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    thumbnail = serializers.ImageField()
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing the method check to look like `if request.method in ['PATCH', 'POST']`, as `request.method` is always a single method.

Answer (score 0):

Any uploaded files should be available in `request.FILES`, a dictionary keyed by the field that they was used when uploading. Once you have the file, it's a matter of handling it similar to any other [uploaded file in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).

If you can, I would use a second serializer that wraps the `Multimedia` model so the image validation and saving can be done automatically through Django REST Framework. There is [an `ImageField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#imagefield) that will automatically validate the image by `Pillow` which you can use on the serializer.