# django rest framework upload file

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I've made it so far to upload file with django rest framework via terminal, Something like this:

```
curl -X POST -S -H -u -F "file=@image.jpg;type=image/jpg" http://127.0.0.1/upload.
```

But how can I use this command via javascript json?
I get error like **unsupported file code 415**?

Can anybody help me out? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit what u exactly want to do?

Comment: I use django rest framework to communicate with phonegap to my backend Django. Now I want to upload file to use django rest framework. Via terminal it works. But I don't get it to use a standard form in the frontend and to upload via post JSON or something like that.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload

Comment: This is my backend:
<code>
class FileUploadView(APIView):
 parser_classes = (JSONParser, MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
 
 def put(self, request, format='jpg'):
  print request.FILES
  up_file =  request.FILES['file']
  destination = open('/var/www/Test/media/' + up_file.name, 'wb+')
  for chunk in up_file.chunks():
   destination.write(chunk)
   destination.close()
  return Response(up_file.name, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

Comment: This is my frontend:

function upload(){  
    var photo = document.getElementById("upload");
    var files = photo.files[0];
                var ajaxRequest = $$.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1/upload",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    processData: false,
                    file: files,

           
                });
            }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 function upload() {

  var photo = document.getElementById("upload");
  var file = photo.files[0];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("PUT", 'http://127.0.0.1/upload', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', ' Token ' + JWT);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
  xhr.send(file);

}
```

Comment: this was the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.