# Django Rest Framework and File Upload

Tags: jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build file upload with DRF and jQuery. I googled and found [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27305713/1907902). I have some similar code on backend:

```
class Attachment(BaseModel):
      file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_photo_path)


class AttachmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Attachment
        fields = ('id', 'file')

class AttachmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )
    serializer_class = serializers.AttachmentSerializer
    queryset = models.Attachment.objects.all()

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.file = self.request.FILES.get('file')
```

And tried to translate Angular sample to jQuery

```
  var fd = new FormData()
  fd.append('file', file) // file from file-field
  var reader = new FileReader()
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8001/files/',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST'
  }).done(...
```

For some reasons I have an error on backend when try to upload a file:

```
detail: "FileUpload parse error - none of upload handlers can handle the stream"
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually the problem is a type of parser. I should use `(FormParser, MultiPartParser, )` instead of `(FileUploadParser, )`

Answer (score 3):

Default Django upload handlers are:

```
["django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler", "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler"]
```

and there is no FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS parameter in the app settings file by default.

In my case I've excluded MemoryFileUploadHandler and set

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ["django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler", ]
```

in app settings file and it solved the problem.