# DRF Upload multiple file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, multiple-file-upload

I'm using DRF to create an user with multiple attachments.
When you create an user you have to upload one or more files.
When I make an update of an user which you load a new file (no other modified field) the response back the old instance.

I solved by forcing the '_prefetched_objects_cache' attribute in the serializer before returning the instance.

```
setattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', True)
```

Is it correct?
You have other solutions about it? 
thanks

There is my code

## in models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
   #field of user model

class Attachment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'attachment'

    path = models.FileField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attachments')
    dt_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
```

## in serializer.py

```
class AttachmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  attachments = AttachmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


  def create(self, validated_data):

      user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

      for file_item in self.initial_data.getlist('attachments'):
         c = Attachment(path=file_item, user=user)
         c.save()
      return user

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
      for item in validated_data:
          if User._meta.get_field(item):
              setattr(instance, item, validated_data[item])

       c = Attachment(path=self.context['request'].FILES['attachments'], user=instance)
       c.save()

       instance.save()
       setattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', True)
       return instance
```

## in test.py

```
io = StringIO.StringIO()
io.write('foo')
file = InMemoryUploadedFile(io, None, 'foo.txt', 'text', io.len, None)
file.seek(0)
self.user['attachments'] = [file, file]
data = self.user
response = self.client.post(url, data, format='multipart')
file = InMemoryUploadedFile(io, None, 'foo2.txt', 'text', io.len, None)
file.seek(0)
#url = url of user detail for update
local_user['attachments'].extend(response.data['attachments'])
local_user['attachments'].append(file)
data = local_user
response = self.client.put(path=url, data=data, format='multipart')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload)

Answer (score 1):

In case you use form for posting to DRF, you could use `FormParser` along with `MultiPartParser` if you're posting your data using forms

ex.

```
...
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
...

class UserView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request):
        ...
```

Files will be available under `request.data` or `request.FILES` as `InMemoryUploadedFile` instance.
You can proceed working with those in serializer or whatever fits better for you view logic.

Don't forget to set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` in your form, otherwise files won't get parsed properly ex.

```
<form action="..." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file-1" />
  <input type="file" name="file-2" />
</form>
```