# django rest fileupload with link returned

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was searching through stackoverflow for example of working fileupload APIView (using DRF of latest versions), I've already tried with many different code samples but none worked (some of them are deprecated, some - isn't what i want)

I have these models:

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    attachment_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    doc = models.FileField(upload_to="docs/", blank=True)
```

I don't wanna use forms and anything else but rest parsers
I want to get POST'ed fields (for example name) in future

I believe the solution is easy but this doesnt work

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        file_obj = request.FILES
        doc = Attachment.objects.create(type="doc", attachment_id=time.time())
        doc.doc = file_obj
        doc.save()
        return Response({'file_id': doc.attachment_id}, status=204)
```

Comment: Doesnt work is not quite descriptive enough ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley in current example it says `AttributeError at /file_upload/
'dict' object has no attribute '_committed'`

Comment: im posting file with header Content-Disposition: file; filename="test", the problem appears after .save() - I simply cant save file

Comment: files is a dict ... perhaps you want `request.FILES['my_file']`

Comment: @JoranBeasley okay, then it writes with no file extension or broken

Comment: here is a blog post from a few months ago that looks relevant ... https://blog.vivekshukla.xyz/uploading-file-using-api-django-rest-framework/ ... (and totally different than what you are doing)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I've tried this, It doesn't create any file (and returns empty list) :(

Comment: keep trying ... im sure it works and im sure youll get there, but you wont be able to get much more help than what you have been given in various google searches ... and its hard with django to provide a [mcve] ...

Comment: Is there a good reason to handle this manually? It seems like you could set `doc` as the default "type" and `time.time()` as the default "attachment_id" and let DRF ViewSets do their thing?

Comment: @MrName 'doc' and `time.time()` are more like an example, I'll manage it my way but what is DRF ViewSets solution? If I could upload file anyhow (safely, without being damaged) then I could simply change Model fields using returned id

Comment: I've also tried to implement solution from May 24 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload) but it seems incompleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removing `parser_class` will solve almost all problems here. Try the following snippet

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        file = request.FILES['filename']
        attachment = Attachment.objects.create(type="doc", attachment_id=time.time(), doc=file)
        return Response({'file_id': attachment.attachment_id}, status=204)
```

**Screenshot of POSTMAN console**
[image]