# POSTMAN -> DJANGO -- Upload Binary file (jpeg). Can't get it to work no matter what I do

Tags: django

to simplify:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://myserver.com/upload' \
--form 'file=@/Users/myname/Desktop/bond.jpg' \
--form 'test=test'
```

It gets to my Django App:

```
class MyUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]
    
    def put(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(request.FILES)
```

but gives out:
<MultiValueDict: {}>

nothing I do work, file is always empty. when I use `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` it doesn't work as well, and sometimes `django` would complain there is no `boundary` -- but any value there gives out the same error.

**MY GOAL IS SIMPLE:**
all I want it to upload a file to django and save it to disk on the backend.

I cannot believe this i taking all day long with zero results and zero examples online that actually work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention that you are developing a REST API but I'm assuming that from your use of `FormParser` and `MultiPartParser`.

In the [example in the Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser) it uses `request.data['file']` not `request.FILES` as you have in your code.

Try changing your method to

```
def put(self, request, **kwargs):
    print(request.data['file'])
```

and see if you get any output.

To save the uploaded file you can do this:

```
def put(self, request, **kwargs):
    uploaded_file = request.data['file']
    destination = open('/Users/Username/' + uploaded_file.name, 'wb+')
    for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
    return Response(uploaded_file.name, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This code borrowed from other posts on SO, such as this one:

[Django Rest Framework File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload)

Comment: how do I save the file to disk?

Comment: @JasonGenX - I've added some information about saving the file