# How to Create an api to upload xml file in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to create an API in Django that will use to take an XML file.

Main Question:
I have created models and serialization and but files that have not to save in Django after extracting the data file will be deleted. now I can not understand the view part(api) please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to upload a file using DRF, you might want to take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473572/django-rest-framework-file-upload). It should give you an idea of what to do