# I am trying to supply data to a serializer related filed but it throws validation error

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to supply data to serializer related field but it keeps throwing a validation error which says the field is required even when I supply a value for it through postman. I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here's are my serializer;

```
class ProjectFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializers):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectFile
        fields = ['project', 'file']


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project_file = ProjectFileSerializer(write_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'budget', 'project_file']
```

Comment: can you share full error

Comment: Here's the exact error I get.
{
    "project_file": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}

Comment: you did not added this field in your question

Comment: you can set required to false if you want

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I listed the field in my ProjectSerializer fields.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I actually need the field required. What I am trying to do is force the user to provide a project file while uploading a project.

Comment: Hello @David i don't know why you are not able to access your uploaded file in serializers maybe you missed some thing you can follow these post if you want to know what you are missing https://stackoverflow.com/a/20473684/14457833 ,  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-upload-fields-in-serializers-django-rest-framework/

Comment: and i am sorry that i can't help you about this because i don't know much about file uploading in using django rest

Comment: Thank you for the assist @AnkitTiwari.
I just checked the references (URLs) you dropped; what I actually meant by "uploading" is when a user is trying to save a project.